# How to count precision and recall for multiclass classification which returns top-5 classes per test example

Tags: classification, precision-recall, multi-class, precision, average-precision

**This is how testing looks like:**

- There is 100 target classes
- The test set consists of 10K elements - each one of them is tagged by one target class
- The distribution of classes over test set is unbalanced

**During the testing:**

- for each one of 10K testing elements - my classifier returns the set of top-5 best matched classes, lets say the set of:

`{c1, c2, c3, c4, c5}`

- only one of them can be true
- rank on which correct prediction appears doesn't matter

**So now the qustion**:

How to count `Precision` and `Recall` for that kind of multiclass classification with top-n results returned?

**I considered here 2 main approaches:**

1. Separately for each class(out of 100) I count: `True Positive(TP)`, `True Negative(TN)`, `False Positive(FP)`, `False Negative(FN)`

   - considering that if one out of 5 returned classes is correct this is: `+1 TP`
   - similarly I count `TN`,`FP`,`FN` - for each class separately
   - after that I can count `Precision` and `Recall` based on `micro-avg` or `macro-avg`.
   - In my case (where distribution of classes over test set is unbalanced) I use `micro-avg`
2. I can count `Precision` and `Recall` for each one of 10K examples separately - treating that:

   - there is max only one `TP` (because only one out of 5 returned classes maybe correct)
   - **if it is found:** `Recall` is `1/1`, `Precision` is `1/5`
   - **if it was not found:** `Recall` is `0/1`, `Precision` is `0/5`
   - After testing all 10K examples - I count `avg-Precision` and `avg-Recall`, simply by summing up all precisions and recalls (separetely) and divide them by number of examples (10K)
   - This approach is called `Precision at rank` and came from `Information Retrieval` field

The second approach seems to me a bit unreasonable so I understand that I should use the first one, but here is the question for you: Did I understood it well and should I go with the first approach?